# Why my local DNS server loses connection when I set primary DNS on my router?

Tags: networking, router, debian, dns, home-networking

I am trying to configure my home DNS server using `bind`.

My network is provided by my router `netis WF2780`.

I have a local computer having the reserved local IP `192.168.1.10`. And I want it to work as a local DNS server.

What I have done:

1. I installed `bind`.
2. In `/etc/bind` I created a file `db.space` with the following content:

   `;
   ; BIND data file for local loopback interface
   ;
   $TTL    604800
   @   IN  SOA ns.space. root.ns.space. (
                     6     ; Serial
                604800     ; Refresh
                 86400     ; Retry
               2419200     ; Expire
                604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL
   ;
   @   IN  NS  ns.space.
   ns  IN  A   192.168.1.10
   my  IN  A   192.168.1.10`
3. I modified the file `named.conf.local` by adding:

   `zone "space" {
       type master;
       file "/etc/bind/db.space";
   };`
4. I modified `named.conf.options` to make it look like this:

   `acl home {
       192.168.1.0/24;
       127.0.0.1;
   };

   options {
       directory "/var/cache/bind";

   ```
   forwarders {
       195.98.160.26;
   };
   recursion yes;

   allow-recursion { home; };
   allow-query { home; };

   auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
   listen-on-v6 { none; };
   ```

   };`
5. I restarted bind:

   `sudo service bind9 restart`
6. In the router settings in the section `WAN Settings` I changed primary and secondary DNS:

   `WAN Connection Type: Dynamic IP (DHCP)
   Primary DNS: 192.168.1.10
   Secondary DNS: 192.168.1.10`

After that my computer with the configured DNS server (with IP 129.168.1.10) lost internet connection. I can't even ping my router:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2083ms
```

And also I can't ping any external website:

```
$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

But this computer can be ping from any other computer in the network:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.10
PING 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=4.50 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=4.43 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=4.94 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.10: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=4.44 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.10 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.432/4.579/4.943/0.222 ms
```

And it resolves my local domain from any computer as well:

```
$ dig @192.168.1.10 +short my.space
192.168.1.10
```

But it can't access to my local website:

```
$ curl my.space
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: my.space
```

Why my computer loses connection to the router and to the internet when I change primary and secondary DNS on the router? I am fully confused with it. What do I have to do to make my local DNS work correctly?

Comment: Can you resolve against your forwarder? What is the response from the command `host www.google.com 195.98.160.26`? In this configuration, bind should forward queries for zones it's not authoritative for.

Comment: Why did you change your router's DNS nameservers? Does the router ever need to resolve the ,space domain? What happens if you reset the router back to your ISP's nameservers?

Comment: @GlennBell I can't resolve hosts via forwarders because the router can't be reached as I mentioned. The router has never resolved the zone `space` before. If I reset the router back, everything works as before: all computer in my local network can be ping and reached, the DNS server resolves all the necessary domains including .space. But if I request `my.space` in browser it can't connect my local website.

Comment: Just as an FYI, local domains often need a trailing slash to resolve correctly in modern Chrome-based browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera).

Comment: @Anaksunaman It didn't help.